# Android Login/Registration using sharedPreference

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, passwords, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to make a Login/Registration activity by using sharedpreference. The app will only hold one login/password information.

So on original start up the app will check if the user has already made an account. This will be kept under a boolean called Registered. If that is true then it will enable the login button and disable the register button. If it is false then it will enable the register button and disable the login button.

When the types in his wanted username and password they can then hit the register button which will set the username and password into strings while changing the boolean to true and then put them in the sharedpreferences. Then the activity will refresh itself.

Currently i cannot get the buttons to change. I think i may be doing sharedpreferences wrong as this is my first time working with them. (Im new to android development.)

Here is my current code.

I have updated the code to include editor.apply()

I have added a few bits and pieces, mainly getting the value at start.

FINAL UPDATE: I have fixed the problem. It seemed to lie within the .setenabled i was using for the buttons. Once i switched them to .setvisibility, they switched perfectly. Thank you all for your help!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText Username_input, Password_input;
String Username, Password;

//if false then no, if true then yes
boolean Registered;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Registered = sharedPref.getBoolean("Registered", false);

    Button RegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Register_btn);
    Button Loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login_btn);

    // If the user is registered.
    if (Registered == false) {

        Loginbutton.setEnabled(false);
        RegisterButton.setEnabled(true);

        // If the user is registered already.
    } else {

        Loginbutton.setEnabled(true);
        RegisterButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Username_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username_input);
            Password_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password_input);
            Username = Username_input.getText().toString();
            Password = Password_input.getText().toString();


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Registered", true);
            editor.putString("Username", Username);
            editor.putString("Password", Password);
            editor.apply();

            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());

        }
    });
}
}
```

XML Code

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/Username_txtview"
    android:id="@+id/Username_txtview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:editable="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Username_input"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Username_txtview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/Password_txtview"
    android:id="@+id/Password_txtview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Username_input"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Username_input"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Username_input" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Password_input"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Password_txtview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Login_btn"
    android:id="@+id/Login_btn"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Register_btn"
    android:id="@+id/Register_btn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Login_btn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you getting registered value from shared preferences before checking if it's true/false?

Comment: will this work for getting the value? Registered = sharedPref.getBoolean("Registered", true);

Comment: post your xml as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Registered = sharedPref.getBoolean("Registered", false);

if (!Registered) {

    Loginbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    RegisterButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // If the user is registered already.
} else{

    Loginbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    RegisterButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Username_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username_input);
        Password_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password_input);
        Username = Username_input.getText().toString();
        Password = Password_input.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Registered", true);
        editor.putString("Username", Username);
        editor.putString("Password", Password);
        editor.apply();

        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (no need of taking shared pref as final)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("hello", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

Boolean register = sharedPref.getBoolean("key",true);
```

and inside register.onClick

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("hello", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();
//your rest of the code to put string values into shared pref here.
editor.putBoolean("key",false);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: If i do not make sharedpref final i get a warning telling me it needs to be declared final. I tryed implementing your code and no change.

Answer (score 0):

add editor.commit() after you put the value into preferences.

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("Registered", Registered);
 editor.putString("Username", Username);
 editor.putString("Password", Password);
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: I've added in editor.commit() and .apply()  No changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are making two mistakes :

- not fetching the registered value from shared preferences before checking it's value initially.
- not doing editor.apply () or editor.commit() after putting new values.

Comment: Ive added the editor.apply(); Now will this work for getting the value? Registered = sharedPref.getBoolean("Registered", true);

Comment: Yes, It should work. but by good design,  the default value (second parameter) should be false instead of true.

Comment: @arthos455 : Uninstall the app from the device that you are testing on before running it again. Shared preferences are persistent among different runs. That might be causing the problem.

Comment: I've been doing a fresh install after each run. I have found the problem though! Seems setting the buttons to enabled or disabled kept them from working. So instead i set the visibility between them and now it works perfectly!